# Disable delete link for lists using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-rest-api, pnp-powershell

I would like to disable/hide delete link for couple of lists. I can easily do with SP scripts but not using PnP/CSOM. Last I looked AllowDelete is not available in the SharePoint.Client library.

Does anyone know a PnP workaround. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Break the permissions and use a modified version of "Contribute" where delete has been removed  as shown here
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/add-pnproledefinition?view=sharepoint-PS
Example 2

Comment: Thanks Kasper. Can't do that the user's they need to be able to delete items. What I am hoping to do is stop content admins from accidentally deleting lists

Comment: Ok, how about breaking the permissions on those specific lists and making the content admins Contribute. Then only the site collection owners will be able to delete the lists.

Comment: Unfortunately for us content admins are also site collection admins/owners. Which is why we want to remove the delete link altogether. I can do it with SP scripts just not with PnP